# Cloned cycle2 won't cycle

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle2

I clone a cycle2 container and I add the content to another container which slides down and I have my dynamically generated area.

```
$(this).closest('ul.cycle-slideshow').clone().addClass('dropped').appendTo('.details-cycle')
            $('.details'). slideDown('slow', function(){
                $(this).addClass('open')
                location.hash = "#" + hash;
            })
```

but cycle2 do not work on cloned element. I have the `ul` but `li` do not slide . What I missed in this case?

Comment: Have you tried `.clone(true)`?

Comment: yes and does not work

Comment: Well, then you can try to initialize copied version with same way as original one.

Comment: I have the cloned data attributes which should work as on the original container